# How to make multiple constructor generic data Class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, data-class

I want to use multple Constructors like this :

```
data class MyData<T>(
    val code: String,
    val message: String,
    val data: T? = null,
) {
    constructor(code: String, message: String) : this(code, message, null)
}
```

and I Use

```
MyData(code = "-1", message = "Support only application/json Content-Type") // Error :  Not Enough Information To Infer Parameter T
MyData(code = "-1", message = "message", data = "data")
```

How to Use MyData property 'data' default value is 'null'?
( I want to MyData(code, message) not MyData(code, message) )

Comment: Your secondary constructor is redundant. By providing a default value for the third parameter, you’ve already created a second constructor that allows you to omit that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the type like this:

```
val obj1 = MyData<String>(code = "-1", message = "Support only application/json Content-Type")
```

Note that *data* should probably be a *var* instead of a *val*, or you won't be able to change it.

Comment: Immutable classes are a valid and often best design practice.

Comment: You said it should probably be a `var` like it’s a mistake to make the class immutable.

Comment: There is a second part in my sentence saying "or you won't be able to change it". Maybe not the best way to put it, I'll give you that.